# Project and then sort in mongoose for array fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a mongoose model for a post on a social-media-like website called PostModel:

```
{
caption: String,
likes: [] // array to store info about users who liked the video, basically a ref to a different model
comments: [] // array to store comment objects
}
```

I want to sort all the videos in a find query based on the number of likes, which here would be the length of the "likes" array. If two posts have same number of likes, I want to sort by the number of comments, or otherwise, the length of the "comments" array.

The problem is that it is not working. This is what I tried:

```
PostModel.find({}, {
  likes: { $size: "$likes" },
  comments: { $size: "$comments" }
}, 
{
  sort: { likes: -1, comments: -1 } // gives "cannot sort with keys that are parallel arrays" error
})
```

This lead me to believe that the sorting happens before the projection. To confirm, I tried the following query:

```
PostModel.find({}, {
  _l: { $size: "$likes" },
  _c: { $size: "$comments" }
}, 
{
  sort: { _l: -1, _c: -1 }
})
```

This query did not give any errors but **did not sort the resultant array at all**. So, it is confirmed that the projection actually happens after the sorting in mongoose.

How should I sort the resultant array by number of likes and number of comments in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out this aggregation and it works perfectly fine for me with your data:

```js
PostModel.aggregate([
  {
    '$set': {
      'likes': {
        '$size': '$likes'
      }, 
      'comments': {
        '$size': '$comments'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'likes': -1, 
      'comments': -1
    }
  }
])
```

I built this aggregation using the Mongo compass program which lets u see the workings of your aggregations live by building it step by step.

Comment: Maybe also check your versions, maybe it doesn't support what you are trying to do right now, and

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason it works with the aggregate() method. I tried your solution and it worked for me. Honestly it's super weird. I couldn't find a difference between find() and aggregate in the mongoose docs, which to be fair are not very informative to begin with.

Comment: I have also already spent hours cursing at the documentations, you are not alone ;)